# Copy files from base image to current building image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

Trying to build an docker image ( X ) using another custom image ( Y ) built by me. Here, I'm trying to copy a folder from base image Y to X as below.

```
FROM some-image as base

COPY --from=base /root/.m2 /root

RUN mkdir -p /build
```

But this is throwing error `invalid from flag value base: pull access denied for base, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 6):

You are not coping from some base image, but you trying to copy in the same image.

> You need to have a second stage to use COPY --from you can not point
>   --from to the same stage you are currently changing.

[docker-cli-issues/1559](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1559)

Here is the simplest example,

- compile c program in the base image
- copy compiled program from base image
- as a result, your end image will be small only **5MB**.

```
FROM alpine as build-env
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
# Compile the binaries
RUN gcc -o hello helloworld.c
FROM alpine
COPY --from=build-env /app/hello /app/hello
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["/app/hello"]
```

hello.c

```
# include <stdio.h>
  int main(){
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/… then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!